# How to install secure OpenSSH server on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, root, sshd, ssh-keys

I want to install OpenSSH server on Ubuntu. How to do it?

I need to do the following:

1. Set up OpenSSH server
2. Set up ssh public-private key pair for user
3. Disable password login
4. Enable root user
5. Set up ssh public-private key pair for root user
6. Set up password

Answer (score 2):

Go to terminal and type:

```
sudo su
aptitude install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Test the installation

```
ps -A | grep sshd
```

If the output is something like this:

```
<some number> ?        00:00:00 sshd
```

Then ssh daemon is running.

Again type in terminal;

```
ss -lnp | grep sshd
```

If the output is something like this:

```
0  128  :::22  :::*  users:(("sshd",16893,4))
0  128   *:22   *:*  users:(("sshd",16893,3))
```

Then it means that ssh daemon is listening for incoming connections

Now we edit the configuration file. First we make a backup of the original file.

```
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults
```

Now we open the configuration file to edit it

```
sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Weak passwords are easy to guess. The best practice is to use SSH keys instead of password.

So we disable password authentication altogether.

Go to the line

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

and replace it with

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Enabling forwarding gives more options to attackers who have already guessed passwords.

So we disable it. It gives us a little security

Go to the lines

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
```

and replace them with

```
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

We can explicitly allow certain users and deny certain users to login.

For that we have to put the following lines at the bottom of the config file.

```
AllowUsers Fred Wilma
DenyUsers Dino Pebbles
```

For optimal performance of laptop we allow two pending connections. Between the third and 
tenth connection the system will start randomly dropping connections 
from 30% up to 100% at the tenth simultaneous connection. This can done by the following line

```
MaxStartups 2:30:10
```

To log more error and other useful information
we alter the line

```
LogLevel INFO
```

into
    LogLevel VERBOSE

To scare away novice attackers we can display a banner
We remove the hash tag from the front of the line

```
#Banner /etc/issue.net
```

to make it

```
Banner /etc/issue.net
```

Then we go to terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/issue.net

***************************************************************************
                        NOTICE TO USERS
This computer system is the private property of its owner, whether
individual, corporate or government.  It is for authorized use only.
Users (authorized or unauthorized) have no explicit or implicit
expectation of privacy.
Any or all uses of this system and all files on this system may be
intercepted, monitored, recorded, copied, audited, inspected, and
disclosed to your employer, to authorized site, government, and law
enforcement personnel, as well as authorized officials of government
agencies, both domestic and foreign.
By using this system, the user consents to such interception, monitoring,
recording, copying, auditing, inspection, and disclosure at the
discretion of such personnel or officials.  Unauthorized or improper use
of this system may result in civil and criminal penalties and
administrative or disciplinary action, as appropriate. By continuing to
use this system you indicate your awareness of and consent to these terms
and conditions of use. LOG OFF IMMEDIATELY if you do not agree to the
conditions stated in this warning.
****************************************************************************
```

Now we save and close the config file and restart ssh by typing in terminal:

```
systemctl restart ssh
```

Next we setup SSH keys
There are two pairs of SSH keys public and private.
Public keys are present in servers and private keys are present with individuals
If someone can match his private key with public key, only he/she can login.
Furthermore optionally private keys can be protected by passphrase
Furthermore when the keys are generated by using 4096 bit encryption
it is almost impossible to break them by brute force

Step one - Create the RSA key pair:

Type in terminal

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

Here we use 64 bit encryption for more security

Step two - Store the keys and passphrase:

Follow the onscreen instructions, give desired location for storage of keys,
reccommended to accept the default, opt for passphrase, give a strong passphrase,
remember it.

The screen is something like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
4a:dd:0a:c6:35:4e:3f:ed:27:38:8c:74:44:4d:93:67 demo@a
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|          .oo.   |
|         .  o.E  |
|        + .  o   |
|     . = = .     |
|      = S = .    |
|     o + = +     |
|      . o + o .  |
|           . o   |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Step three - Copy the Public Key:

Type in terminal

```
ssh-copy-id user@123.45.56.78
```

Here 123.45.56.78 is the server IP address

In case of localhost it is

```
ssh-copy-id user@localmachinename
```

The screen is something like this

```
The authenticity of host '12.34.56.78 (12.34.56.78)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b1:2d:33:67:ce:35:4d:5f:f3:a8:cd:c0:c4:48:86:12.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '12.34.56.78' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@12.34.56.78's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'user@12.34.56.78'", and check in:

~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

Now our installation is complete. To login we need to type in terminal:

```
ssh username@servername
```

Then when prompted for passphrase we need to provide it.

Now we  to enable root login of opessh server
We first have to enable sudo password as it is disabled in Ubuntu by default.

For that, we type in terminal the following, screen will be something like this:

```
sudo passwd
[sudo] password for [username]: [Type your user password and press return]
Type new UNIX password: [Type the root password you want]
Retype new UNIX password: [Retype the root password you chosen before]
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Now we have to edit the /etc/sudoers file.

Here we use the editor called visudo

It is because visudo is for the sole purpose of editing sudoes file

In ubuntu by default config files are opened by nano editor

To change it type in terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

The following screen will appear:

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Type 3 and press enter

Then type:

```
sudo visudo
```

Move to the line which reads

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

Press enter

Above a new line gets created

Type:

Defaults    rootpw

use spacebar, not TAB

Press Esc --> :x --> Enter

In terminal type:

```
gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Move to the line:

```
PermitRootLogin password-prohibited
```

and change it to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Next move to the line:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and change it to

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Save and close

Then restart SSH

```
service ssh restart
```

Now it's time to again generate the ssh public-private key pair for the user root.

Type in terminal

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

Step two - Store the keys and passphrase:

Follow the onscreen instructions, give desired location for storage of keys,
DON'T accept the default as you have to crete  new pair this time,
the default one has lready been created, opt for passphrase, give a strong passphrase,
remember it.

The screen is something like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa): u-root-id_rsa 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/u-root-id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/u-root-id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
4a:dd:0a:c6:35:4e:3f:ed:27:38:8c:74:44:4d:93:67 demo@a
The key's randomart image is:

+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|          .oo.   |
|         .  o.E  |
|        + .  o   |
|     . = = .     |
|      = S = .    |
|     o + = +     |
|      . o + o .  |
|           . o   |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Then type in terminal:

```
ssh-copy-id -i u-root-id_rsa.pub root@localmachinename
```

Output  screen may show:

```
The authenticity of host '12.34.56.78 (12.34.56.78)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b1:2d:33:67:ce:35:4d:5f:f3:a8:cd:c0:c4:48:86:12.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '12.34.56.78' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@12.34.56.78's password:
```

Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'user@12.34.56.78'", and check in:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

Now we have granted private key access to root to login

To test type:

```
ssh root@localmachine
```

Again in terminal type:

```
gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

move to the line:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

and change it to

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Save and close

Then restart SSH

```
service ssh restart
```

It will ask for passphrase. Passphrase remains the same. Give it.

Now the root will be able to successfully login

Now for more security we have to add firewall

Type:

```
apt install ufw
```

Now start it

```
enable ufw
```

Get a list of currently running processes

```
ufw app list
```

OpenSSH will be listed there.

```
ALow it through firewall
ufw allow OpenSSH
```

Restart firewall

```
systemctl restart ufw
```

Our installation is complete